# Como pegar o maior valor com o maior comprimento no mysql no order by desc?

Tags: sql

Eu tenho uma sequência de valores, por exemplo:

```
w1-16
w2-16
w3-16
w4-16
w5-16
w6-16
w7-16
w8-16
w9-16
w10-16
w11-16
```

Por ai vai.

Fiz uma query que pega a sequência correta como esta acima. Exemplo:

```
select week from tabela where group by week order by length(week), week;
```

tentei colocar o `desc` no fim mais vem tudo em desordem, eu gostaria de pegar o maior valor com o maior comprimento como no exemplo da sequencia acima o valor `w11-16` o ultimo valor não é fixo ele pode mudar em caso de inserção na tabela alguém sabe uma maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Tire o `length(week)`

Comment: Quem tem precedência? O maior valor ou maior comprimento?

Comment: que pegar os dois valores, na verdade quero pegar o ultimo valor inserido